# Получение массива по запросу Mysql

Tags: c#, .net

Я выполняю запрос MySql, где получаю столбец Id с несколькими значениями. Как я могу получить все эти значения Int массивом?

```
MySqlCommand selectIds = mysqlConnection.CreateCommand();
selectIds.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
mysqlConnection.Open();
MySqlDataReader selectIds_mysqlReader = selectIds.ExecuteReader();
while (selectIds_mysqlReader.Read())
{
Ids =selectIds_mysqlReader.GetString("Id");
}
```

Comment: у вас есть код и база и схема, но вы, имея все это не могли понять ответ. Вы предполагаете, что мы, не видя ничего этого, сможем вам что то подсказать?

Comment: Поправил  код, посмотрите

Comment: ну вы тут перезаписываете одну и ту же переменную, разве нет? `Ids =selectIds_mysqlReader.GetString("Id");`

Comment: У меня в итоге при выводит одно значение, а как получить массив Id? Каждый Id это строка в столбце

Comment: ну вот смотрите. Для начала, я бы запрашивал из БД только то, что нужно. Вам же только Id надо? Вот и запрашивайте только Id `"SELECT Id FROM `users`"`

Comment: После я бы создал где то список, куда я буду складывать айдишники, типа `var result = new List<int>();`

Comment: Потом, уже в цикле, я бы просто добавлял число в список, типа `while (selectIds_mysqlReader.Read()) result.Add(selectIds_mysqlReader.GetInt("Id"););`